# Find the invariant elements and the degree of the $R$-module $M=\mathbb{C}^3$ where $R$ is the polynomial ring $R=\mathbb{C}[T]$ where $T(w)=Aw$

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &-2  & 1\\ 
>  1&  -2& 1\\ 
>  1&  -2& 1
> \end{pmatrix}$.
>
> Find the invariant elements and the degree of the $R$-module $M=\mathbb{C}^3$ where $R$ is the polynomial ring $R=\mathbb{C}[T]$ where $T(w)=Aw$.

**A start of an attempt:**

We know that $\mathbb{C}^3\cong (\mathbb{C}[x])^r\oplus \bigoplus_{i=1}^nR/\langle a_i\rangle $.
There's a surjective homomorphism $\phi:R^3\to M$ which is $\phi:(\mathbb{C}[x])^3\to \mathbb{C}^3$ which I'm not sure how to define $\phi(f_1,f_2,f_3)$.

Then we wish to find the relations module $\ker(\phi)$.

Comment: What do you mean by invariant element and degree?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with notice that all elements in $ \mathbb{C} $ are torsion elements;
 if $ p_T(x) $ is the minimal polynomial for $ T $, 
    then $ p_T(x).v = 0 $ for all vectors $ v\in \mathbb{C} $.
Hence we even know that, as a $ \mathbb{C}[x] $-module,
$$ \mathbb{C}^3 \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{C}[x]/\langle p_i(x) \rangle, $$

where $ p_i $ are the invariant elements.
Not sure what you mean by degree though, is it the degree of the minimal polynomial $ p_T $?
Anyways, we know that $ B = xI - A $ is the relation matrix 
so the relations of $ \ker \phi $ are generated by $ eB = 0 $, where $ e = (e_1 \; e_2 \; e_3) $.
In order to find the invariant elements we need to get $ B $ on its smith normal form.
After some row and column operations we get that
$$ B \sim C = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & x & 0\\
0 & 0 & x^2
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{wherefore} 
\quad \mathbb{C}^3 \cong \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\langle x \rangle} 
\oplus \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\langle x^2 \rangle}. $$
Hence the invariant elements are $ x $ and $ x^2 $.
To be more precise we have that $ C = PBQ $, where
$$ P = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
x+1 & -2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}. $$
Hence 
\begin{align*}
0 &= eB = eP^{-1}PB = eP^{-1}PBQ = eP^{-1}C 
\\
&= (e_1+e_2+(1-x)e_3\quad e_2+2e_3 \quad e_3) \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & x & 0\\
0 & 0 & x^2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*} 
Thus the sought relations are $ x^2.e_3 = 0 $ and $ x.(e_2+2e_3) = 0 $
so that $ \ker \phi = \langle x^2.e_3, x.(e_2+2e_3) \rangle$.